# Is there something similar to GUnload() in google maps v3?

Tags: google-maps, memory-leaks

In Google Maps v2 we had `onunload="GUnload()"`. Now in the newer version v3 I couldn't find this function in the api.

I'm asking because I have some troubles with memoryleaks in combination with Google Maps v3.

Comment: What kind of memory leaks? Do you have a sample page to reproduce these problems? Have you filed an issue here:

http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/

Comment: I have these problems/memory leaks on http://www.susi.at/suchen/ 
I'm using the Firefox-Extension 'Leak Monitor' getting errorreports like: [leaked object] (6280220, http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/de_ALL/mapfiles/api-3/2/9/main.js, 8-8) = [Function]

Answer (score 5):

It appears there should be no requirement to call GUnload in v3

http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=772#c18http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=772#c18

Comment: There is a requirement if we're talking about a web application that doesn't have an onunload event fire.